# eclipse market place is giving error during installing of glass Fish

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, java-8, installation, glassfish-4.1

[image]These pics clearly shows that eclipse market place give error that following solution is not available  and at the end it turns to alternative solution and then finally error and stopped.

Comment: The Eclipse Marketplace lists features and where they can be downloaded, in your case from _oracle.com_. If something is missing to install the selected feature, this might can be fixed by adding an update site. Which update page to add depends on what is missing.

Comment: Salo answer de war do

Comment: I do not understand you. Can you please say that in more detail in English?